# is it possible to change modifier of variables and methods in interface

Tags: java, interface

modifiers in variables in an interface are `public`, `static`, `final` by default. But how can I do if I want it to be private so that no other classes can call this variable

Comment: I can see why you could use private in an interface for some methods, but what would you want a private variable ?

Comment: so is this feasible?

Comment: What do you mean by "call this variable"? Variables are accessed, _methods_ are called. You cannot call a variable.

Comment: sorry, my expression is not accurate

Comment: @Kartone No, it is not possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Declaring a class to implement an interface is a promise that this class provides these methods, or extensions thereof. Increasing/*extending* access to the methods is allowed, but decreasing access is not, because then we would break our promise.

This is similar to classes and *extensions* of them, subclasses. A subclass has to provide all methods of the superclass with *at least* the visibility they were declared with.

The reason for this is the statically typed nature of Java. If a type may differ from its initial declaration in such a way that it breaks (access to) the type, then it makes the whole static-typing obsolete.

Fields (also called member variables) are different in the way that their access cannot be extended. Declaring another member variable of similar name on a subclass is exactly that, *another variable.* By doing this, you hide the superclass' variable, and you may have to use the keyword `super` to access it.

Comment: Thanks for answering, but I'm still confused. My question's priority is not about ```private``` itself, but about whether it's feasible to change the modifier of variable along with methods. Since in interface, variables' modifier is public, static and final, and methods' modifier is public and abstract. So can I change modifier later?

Comment: @Kartone No, it is not possible.